# Run javascript function and stop either after 5 seconds or condition is met?

Tags: javascript, loops, timer

I need to write in a pure JavaScript function which will execute only for 5 seconds and will stop if either one of the following conditions (whichever comes first)

1. 5 seconds has elapsed
2. user inputted a field

I could only do condition 2 but can't figure out how to break the loop after 5 seconds:

```
function beginScanningForItemVer2(){
    var userInput= false;
    var element;
    while (!userInput){
        element = document.getElementById("input").value;
        if (element != null){
            userInput= true;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks guys for helping me. Please keep helping me...
It seems I cannot use a while loop for detecting user input because my CPU usage goes up really fast while on the loop. Is there any way to accomplish both of these? Please help me

Comment: You can not use a while loop while waiting for user input in the DOM. use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout)

Comment: hi sir, thanks for the reply. But I could detect it on my browser. But I think I should not use while loop for scanning because I observed that my cpu usage goes up dramatically while on the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript tends to be very callback oriented, since by default all the Javascript on a page runs in a single thread, which means that the UI isn't responsive while other code is busy running. So rather than looping in a function and looking for input on each loop, you likely want to register a callback function which will be called when your input element experiences a change -- for example, the `onchange` listener will run your callback whenever the value of the element changes. You could unregister this callback 5 seconds later to stop anything from happening if the user inputs something after the 5 seconds are up.

Sparse example (referencing http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp):

```
// Set a function to be called when the value of the input element changes.
object.onchange = function() { 
  valueAfterChange = document.getElementById("input").value;
  // Do something with valueAfterChange.
}

// window.setInterval calls a function after a set delay.
window.setInterval(function() { 
  object.onchange = null;
  // Anything else you might want to do after 5 seconds.
}, 5000);   // Call this function after 5000 milliseconds == 5 seconds.
```

Comment: no sir, I cannot add an event on the element. I just need the function

Comment: As you've discovered, waiting in a loop will use a lot of CPU. This is because the processor is actively going around in the loop! During this time, nothing else can happen in your site, including the user interacting with the input box, since the processor is busy executing your loop over and over again. This is just the way of the world in Javascript, you'll have to use callbacks to handle things like this.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an active issue, maybe you could try this:

```js
const endTime = Date.now() + 5000; // set your cutoff
const scanning = setInterval(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById('input').value;
    if (element) {
        clearInterval(scanning);
    }
    if (endTime < Date.now()) {
        clearInterval(scanning);
    }
}, 1000 /* interval in ms */)
```

Where you set an interval to scan every second (or however often you want), and then you can set a condition to stop the interval if it passes the 5 second mark.

Comment: This is actually not a great solution, but I would check out this article for polling: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/polling-in-javascript-ab2d6378705a

Answer (score -1):

**Eddited**

You could combine `setInterval` and `setTimeout` to solve . Your code will look like this.

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var userInput= false;
    var element;
    while (!userInput){
        element = document.getElementById("input").value;
        if (element != null){
            userInput= true;
        }
    }
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}, 5000)
```

You could see more information here. Cheers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers

Comment: but as I read, timeout just delays the execution of a function. What I'm looking for is when I invoked that function, it will start running for only 5 seconds or if user has inputted the field.